# Qt and pointers

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I'm new to Qt and I'm reading several Qt Projects to get the basics.
While browsing the different classes it seems that pointers to QWidget are always used.

**Exemple :**

```
class ExempleWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ExempleWidget();
    ~ExempleWidget();

private:
    QPushButton * m_stopButton;
    QPushButton * m_playButton;

    QHBoxLayout * m_hBoxLayout;
    QVBoxLayout * m_vBoxLayout;
};
```

Is there any reason for using pointers for *'QPushButton'* *'QHBoxLayout'* etc. ? 
Can we just use values so we don't have to bother with *'new'* and *'delete'*? Well I know we can but is it a good way to do it?

E.g.

```
private:
    QPushButton m_stopButton;
```

**EDIT :**

All answers seems to point out the hierarchy between Qt classes. 
It's a good enough reason for me and I don't doubt of the point but let's say that there is no link between the widgets of my class (*m_stopButton* and *m_playButton*).

I can safely declare them as values in this case, can't I? 
When the class will be deleted, the members will be deleted too so pointers or not we will have the same behavior.

Comment: You should read about [object trees and ownership](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/objecttrees.html).

Comment: about your edit: If those buttons are top level, yeah go ahead. but you need to put them in a layout. Which is in a widget. So there is a link between your buttons and ***another*** widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in constructor you can give them a parent, so when parent is deleted they are deleted too automatically.

There can be also other reasons, depending on the project (like creating and destroying methods depending on class logic).

Comment: The fact that Qt has a garbage collection is not a reason to use dynamically allocated objects. Therefore this is **not** an answer. @MSalters

Comment: How about because its a parent TREE so it affects the layout and how they are displayed.

Comment: Infact, it's depends on class logic.

Comment: @paulm "When QObjects are created on the heap (i.e., created with new), a tree can be constructed from them in any order [...] When QObjects are created on the stack, the same behavior applies." -- [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html).

Comment: Yeah - if you want it to crash, setting the parent takes ownership of the pointer.

Comment: @Jefffrey The doc you've link shows the real problem with using stack-based QObjects, explained from: "But now consider what happens if we swap the order of construction, as shown in this second snippet". The order the objects have been declared now matters and can be a problem.

Comment: @JBL In C++, the order of construction/destruction of class members has "always" been linked to the order of their declaration. This is not magic, it's something everyone is expected to know and depend on. You're not supposed to randomly swap the order of construction/destruction and expect things to work. That's just silly.

Comment: @KubaOber I fully agree. Yet it's still error prone. That should be a concern, though if you know what you're doing, you can actually go with non-dynamic variables. Good ol' "C++ gives you tools to shoot you in the foot".

Comment: @jeffrey Thanks for this link. With this constructor signature you are very limited

Answer (score 6):

You'd want to use the pointers when you wish have full control over the object's lifetime. For example

1. If you want to construct a class member at some point after the initialization list in the constructor has been processed.
2. If you want to destruct a class member at some point before the compiler-generated destructor epilogue runs.

It is perfectly safe not to use the pointers when you are OK with the compiler constructing and destructing the object instances for you.

Raw pointers turn out to be error-prone whenever they *own* the resource they point to: it's an error to forget to delete the owned resource, to delete the resource multiple times, or to dereference an already-deleted resource.

Use of raw pointers (as opposed to smart pointers) that do not *own* the resource - when the resource will be freed by someone else - may still be a case of premature optimization. The use of raw pointers is prone to turn "small" code changes into resource leaks:

```
class X : public QObject {
  QObject * a;
public:
  // OK
  X() : a(new QObject(this)) {}
  // an error - we need to add a destructor that deletes a
  X() : a(new QObject) {}
}

class X : public QObject P
  QScopedPointer<QObject> a;
public:
  // Both OK
  X() : a(new QObject(this)) {}
  X() : a(new QObject) {}
};
```

The smart pointers - C++11's `std::unique_ptr`, Qt 4.6's `QScopedPointer` - guarantee that the deletion always happens, and that access to a deleted resource is equivalent to a null pointer dereference and thus nominally caught and signaled by the processor hardware.

In C++, the order of construction and destruction of class members and automatic variables is *fixed*. In the examples below, the construction order is *always* `a` then `b`, and the destruction order is *always* `b` then `a`. This is **very important**.

```
class C {
  A a;
  B b;
};

void test() {
  A a;
  B b;
}
```

Thus, the following code is valid and behaves correctly under at least Qt 3, Qt 4 and Qt 5, unless specified otherwise.

```
class C : public QWidget {
  QWidget a;
  QLabel b;
public:
  C(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), a(this), b(&a) {}
}

// Qt 4.6 & up only
class C : public QWidget {
  QScopedPointer<QWidget> a;
  QScopedPointer<QLabel> b;
public:
  C(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), 
                            a(new QWidget(this)),
                            b(new QLabel(a.data())) {}
};

// C++11 only
class C : public QWidget {
  std::unique_ptr<QWidget> a;
  std::unique_ptr<QLabel> b;
public:
  C(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), 
                            a(new QWidget(this)), 
                            b(new QLabel(a.data())) {}
};      

void test() {
  QWidget c;
  QWidget a(&c);
  QLabel b(&a);
}
```

In all cases, the construction order is: `c, a, b`; the destruction order is: `b, a, c`.

Comment: Well, I think (hope) I'm ok with objects' lifetime in C++. My question was more specific about Qt.

In a lots of codes I've seen pointers with a _new_ in the construction, a _delete_ in destructor and nothing else other than that (just methords calls but no parents or childs etc.).
So I wanted to be sure that I did not miss anything specific to Qt.

Answer (score 5):

Qt is basically designed as C++ anno 1996 or so (or very Java-esque, if you will). Lots of pointers, lots of inheritance.

Of course one reason they frequently use pointers is that inheritance is virtually everywhere, and it avoids any slicing-related issues.

Another reason is that Qt has a strong convention that memory management is handled by giving every object a parent, so that when the parent is destroyed, it calls `delete` on its children.

If you declare your object as a local object instead of a pointer to something allocated with `new`, then you have to be careful about either not giving it a parent, or otherwise ensuring that it goes out of scope before its parent to ensure `delete` is never called.

Comment: Where would slicing come into play? Surely one would be passing around references/pointers to one's stack-allocated objects, which retain dynamic type/polymorphism. Anyway, it seems notable that `gtkmm` advises stack allocation by default - seemingly having no problems at all with order of parent vs child destruction, handling both cases transparently and without issue. Maybe it does so by leveraging the underlying GTK+ reference-counting machinery that Qt didn't have and wasn't willing to add, not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a reason. All subclasses of `QObject` can be put in a hierarchy using the `parent` attribute. It is very useful because It allows an action on a `QObject` to be propagated to all the children hierarchy. One of these actions is `show` or `hide` for widgets, another is object destruction.

When you delete a `QObject` (ie a `Qwidget` too), all of his children are also deleted. [as the doc says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#dtor.QObject)

> Warning: All child objects are deleted. If any of these objects are on
>   the stack or global, sooner or later your program will crash

Furthermore you can move objects to other threads. In order to do that you need those object to be on a memory region which is available to all threads in a process. The stack is for a single thread, so it not appropriate.

***On a pure language perspective***, You only have the constructor

```
QObject::QObject( QObject * parent = 0 );
```

If you provide a value to parent different to `NULL`, this value should have a lifetime greater than the object being constructed. Otherwise It might use an invalid reference.

Basically they had different mechanisms they wanted to put in place, and with different constraints (including *backward compatibility*), it is the one they chose.

Comment: Note that the childs here are neither on the stack nor global, so that quote is irrelevant.

Comment: Passing a pointer to something on the stack which is then deleted will crash, so it is relevant

Comment: I think MSalters' point is that having a (non-pointer) `QWidget` member does not mean it's on the stack nor global. The `delete` will still crash, of course... but because the object is a subobject of a different allocation, not because it was stack or global memory.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is historical. In older Qt versions, when you pass the parent widget to the constructors of the member widgets, the parent `QWidget::~QWidget` calls `delete` on the child widgets.

In current Qt versions a check has been added to see if the child widget has already been deleted, which means you can now make them ordinary members.

Comment: Again, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173584/qt-and-pointers#comment33653981_22173751)

Comment: There is no such "check". C++ has fixed order of construction and destruction of members of an object instance. A child object can be destructed at any time, and the objects always have dealt with it correctly. Even in Qt 3, and I'm sure earlier than that too.

Comment: @KubaOber: In Qt3, you used the pointer style from the question, and the child was **not** deleted at any time. The parent was exclusively responsible for deletion and did so exactly once. (I started using Qt back in 2003, rule might have been relaxed any time since)

Comment: @MSalters The parent only did the deletion of children that *existed*. You were free to add and remove children dynamically, and this is what happens in the scenario in the question. The child will be destructed (removed from the parent) before the parent is destructed, and thus the parent won't attempt to *delete* the child because, well, there's no child anymore.

Comment: the historical reason is valid imho. +1

Comment: @KubaOber: The scenario you describe fails if a child is deleted before it's removed from its parent. And no, the destructor of the parent widget can't do that, because it hasn't even started when the child destructor has completed.

Comment: @MSalters childs not in term of inheritance but in term of reverse relation of `setParent`

Comment: @MSalters How would you delete a child before it's removed from its parent in Qt 3? An how would it fail? Show the code.

Comment: @KubaOber: Straightforward:  `class QParent : QWidget { QMyObject member; };`. Before `QWidget::~QWidget` starts, `QMyObject::~QMyObject` has finished.

Comment: @MSalters Object deletion here implies removal from the parent, so that's perfectly fine.